# Facebook + WordPress

Tags: facebook, wordpress

being surfing a while on a topic.

site : http://www.udaipurtimes.com

The problem is, I have a WordPress site and I've used FB Share and FB Like plugins (free) for displaying on each posts. I also have a fan page of the website where I regularly update about every post I do on website. But for example if someone like that post on FB fanpage, then it dosen't reflect on to my website's Fb Like counter.

Example, If one post receives 10 likes on FB fanpage, then that same post on my website just have 2 likes. Basically, I want to sync these like between my website's post and the post that I link then to Fb fanpage.

Do revert back to this. Anything from your end would be helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

We need to designate that the content being liked on FB and the content being liked on your WP Site are not one in the same. If it is liked on FB, the count will not show up on your page(and vise versa).

There's not a lot you can do. This is very much a part of how Facebook works.

However, it's a good idea to keep your content organized with Open Graph. Hope this helps.

http://ogp.me/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/